# Why D/I is finite if I is a non-zero ideal of the ring of integers of a number field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

Let D be the ring of integers of a number field K. Let I be a non-zero ideal of D. Why D/I is finite?

Would you help me please? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Think about quotient of free abelian groups then $\mathcal{O}_K / \alpha \mathcal{O}_K  \simeq \mathbb{Z}^n / A \mathbb{Z}^n$ for some matrix $A \in \mathbb{Z}^{n \times n}$ inversible over $\mathbb{Q}$ representing the multiplication by $\alpha$, and the number of elements in the quotient is $|\det(A)|$

Answer (score 4):

Let $\alpha$ be a nonzero element of $I$. Then $D/I$ is a quotient
of $D/(\alpha)$ so we can reduce to the case where $I=(\alpha)$ is finite.
As an Abelian group $D$ is free of some finite rank $n$. Let $u_1,\ldots,u_n$ be generators of this Abelian group. Then
$I$ is freely generated by the $\alpha u_i$. Then $\alpha u_i=\sum_ja_{i,j}u_j$ for integers $a_{i,j}$. The $\alpha u_i$ are
linearly independent over $\Bbb Q$, so the matrix $A=(a_{i,j})$ is non-singular. If $b=\det A$ then $bD\subseteq I$. As $bD$
has finite index $|b|^n$ in $D$, then so does $I$.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, the ideal I contains some integer, so that D/I is a quotient of D/(n). Since D is a free abelian group of some finite rank r this quotient of a sum of r copies of the cyclic group of order n.

Comment: Suarez-Alvarez Thank you for your answer. I do not understand what does it mean that D/I is a quotient of D/(n) :(

Comment: D/(n) is a ring and D/I is a quotient of that ring by the ideal I/(n).

Comment: Could someone please elaborate on why $I$ contains some integer?

Comment: @Ribbity Let $\alpha \in I \setminus \{0\}$ (trivially, $I$ contains the integer $0$, but that doesn't help us here). Then on the one hand, $N(\alpha) \in \mathbb{Z}\setminus \{0\}$, and on the other hand, since $N(\alpha)$ is a product of conjugates of $\alpha$ including $\alpha$ we have $N(\alpha) \in I$.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Could you please elaborate on your last statement? It sounds a bit like that you are using the property that $I$ is an ideal but I am not sure.

If $\alpha_1 = \alpha, \dots,  \alpha_n$ are the conjugates of $\alpha$, then it is $N(\alpha) = \prod \alpha_i \in I$. If $\alpha_2 \cdots \alpha_n \in D$, then your statement is true - but this is where I am stuck.

Comment: @Ribbity Let $G = \operatorname{Gal}(G,\mathbb{Q})$, then $$N(\alpha) = \prod_{\varphi \in G} \varphi(\alpha)$$ (note that several of the $\varphi$ may fix $\alpha$ - all of them do if $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}$). Since $\varphi(\alpha)$ has the same minimal polynomial as $\alpha$, all of these are algebraic integers, and of course they belong to $K$. But $D$ is the ring of integers in $K$, so they all lie in $D$.